# Windows 7 installer not showing FileInUse Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer, file-in-use

I have created an installer in visual studio following normal procedure. I run my application. Task manager is showing it. I keep it open/running, and go to uninstall the application. But, windows (in which visual studio is not installed) does not show fileinuse dialog. I have checked the problem in a fresh windows 7 machine in which visual studio is not installed. Does any extra package is installed during visual studio installation which helps showing the fileinuse dialog?

Comment: any support from restart manager included in the app/installer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372466(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, restart manager support is included in the app by the following line of code in the constructor:                            m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags = AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_ALL_ASPECTS;